# Why in an elongating string we can not use Newton's law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

[image]

I am trying to solve this question using newton law
$$ mg- kx = ma$$
When there is maximum elongation then $a=0$
$$mg=kx$$
$$x=mg/k$$
Here why i am getting different result?

Answer (score 1):

Maximum elongation is not when a = 0 but when the velocity equals zero.

Answer (score 1):

Th maximum elongation is not an equilibrium position. So the net force is not zero and neither is the acceleration. What is zero at maximum elongation is the velocity. The velocity of the sleeve increases until it reaches the catch. Then the velocity decreases as the string is extended, goes through the equilibrium position (mg=kx) and keeps going (while continuing to slow down) to the maximum elongation.

So there is nothing wrong with Newton's laws if they are used for the actual conditions of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the point of maximum elongation $a\ne 0$. If you’ve ever saw elastic core, you can remember that the mass $m$ will be lifted up by a core, after getting to the point of maximum elongation, which means that it has an acceleration forwarded upwards, which is definitely non-zero.